# DNN UrlControl Loads Parent Portal Pages on Child Portal

Tags: dotnetnuke

Stack Overflow gurus,

I have a site running DNN 6.x that has a settings page for a DotNetNuke module that uses DNN's UrlControl.  The problem is, when the module is loaded on a child portal, the UrlControl lists the pages from the parent portal and not the child portal.

Any ideas why and how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Did you make the module by your self? Did you used editURl, NavifationURl for the link?

Comment: I've simply declared the UrlControl on a page with the following two lines of code.

    `<%@ Register TagPrefix="dnn" TagName="UrlControl" Src="~/controls/urlcontrol.ascx" %>`
    `<dnn:UrlControl ID="urlControl" runat="server" ShowLog="false" ShowUsers="false" ShowNewWindow="false" ShowTrack="false" />`

When the user selects the "Page (A Page On Your Site)" option, they get a list of pages from the parent portal in the dropdown list.  I want them to see the list of pages on the child portal.  I hope this clarifies.